# Computing minimum distance between a row and all previous rows in R

Tags: r

I want to compute the minimum distance between the current row and every row before it within each group. My data frame has several groups, and each group has multiple dates with longitude and latitude.  I use a Haversine function to compute distance, and I need to apply this function as described above. The data frame looks like the following:

```
  grp    date    long lat rowid
1   1 1995-07-01   11  12     1
2   1 1995-07-05    3   0     2
3   1 1995-07-09   13   4     3
4   1 1995-07-13    4  25     4
5   2 1995-03-07   12   6     1
6   2 1995-03-10    3  27     2
7   2 1995-03-13   34   8     3
8   2 1995-03-16   25   9     4
```

My current attempt uses purrrlyr::by_row, but the method is too slow. In practice, each group has thousands of dates and geographic positions. Here is part of my current attempt:

```
calc_min_distance <- function(df, grp.name, row){
  df %>% 
    filter(
      group_name==grp.name
    ) %>% 
    filter(
      row_number() <= row
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
      last.lat = last(lat),
      last.long = last(long),
      rowid = 1:n()
    ) %>% 
    group_by(rowid) %>% 
    purrrlyr::by_row(
      ~haversinedistance.fnct(.$last.long, .$last.lat, .$long, .$lat),
      .collate='rows',
      .to = 'min.distance'
    ) %>% 
    filter(
      row_number() < n()
    ) %>% 
    summarise(
      min = min(min.distance)
    ) %>% 
    .$min
}

df_dist <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(grp_name) %>% 
  mutate(rowid = 1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(grp_name, rowid) %>% 
  purrrlyr::by_row(
    ~calc_min_distance(df, .$grp_name,.$rowid),
    .collate='rows',
    .to = 'min.distance'
  ) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-rowid)
```

Suppose that distance is defined as (lat + long) for reference row - (lat + long) for each pairwise row less than the reference row. My expected output for grp 1 is the following:

```
  grp       date long lat rowid min.distance
1   1 1995-07-01   11  12     1            0
2   1 1995-07-05    3   0     2          -20
3   1 1995-07-09   13   4     3           -6
4   1 1995-07-13    4  25     4            6
```

How can I quickly compute the minimum distance between the current rowid and all rowids before it?

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and also include your expected output. I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do and what your expected output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Without seeing your code there's no reason to think any other method would be faster. Your problem necessitates calculating all pairwise distances within each group, that's about 500k distance calculations for a group of 1000 points, 12.5M calculations for 5000 points. I'd hope you're computing distance matrices for each group and then picking the appropriate minimums out...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it. You need to calculate all the within-group pair-wise distances anyway, so we'll use `geosphere::distm` which is designed to do just that. I'd suggest stepping through my function line-by-line and looking at what it does, I think it will make sense.

```
library(geosphere)
find_min_dist_above = function(long, lat, fun = distHaversine) {
  d = distm(x = cbind(long, lat), fun = fun)
  d[lower.tri(d, diag = TRUE)] = NA
  d[1, 1] = 0
  return(apply(d, MAR = 2, min, na.rm = TRUE))
}

df %>% group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(min.distance = find_min_dist_above(long, lat))
# # A tibble: 8 x 6
# # Groups:   grp [2]
#     grp date        long   lat rowid min.distance
#   <int> <fct>      <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>
# 1     1 1995-07-01    11    12     1           0 
# 2     1 1995-07-05     3     0     2     1601842.
# 3     1 1995-07-09    13     4     3      917395.
# 4     1 1995-07-13     4    25     4     1623922.
# 5     2 1995-03-07    12     6     1           0 
# 6     2 1995-03-10     3    27     2     2524759.
# 7     2 1995-03-13    34     8     3     2440596.
# 8     2 1995-03-16    25     9     4      997069.
```

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = '  grp    date    long lat rowid
1   1 1995-07-01   11  12     1
2   1 1995-07-05    3   0     2
3   1 1995-07-09   13   4     3
4   1 1995-07-13    4  25     4
5   2 1995-03-07   12   6     1
6   2 1995-03-10    3  27     2
7   2 1995-03-13   34   8     3
8   2 1995-03-16   25   9     4', h = TRUE)
```